# how can i search for values that have "-" dash in them with elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

my entry in elastic search is like this:

input:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/4" -d'
{
     "uid": "a-b"
}'
```

query :

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/_search" -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "uid": "a-b" }
    }
}'
```

output:

```
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it entirely depends on the analyser you are using.

With the standard analyser you can see that two tokens have been generated and the "-" is ignored.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/_analyze?analyzer=standard&pretty' -d 'a-b'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
        "token" : "a",
        "start_offset" : 0,
        "end_offset" : 1,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 1
  }, {
        "token" : "b",
        "start_offset" : 2,
        "end_offset" : 3,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

With the whitespace analyser the "-" is treated as data and you only get one token out for your data:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/_analyze?analyzer=whitespace&pretty' -d 'a-b'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
        "token" : "a-b",
        "start_offset" : 0,
        "end_offset" : 3,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

When you use **term** query no analysis is done on the search query. 
So you are probably trying to match "a-b" against "a" and "b" (assuming you've used the standard analyser in your mapping) - i.e. it won't match and won't return results.

If you has used **match** or **query_string** in your query your search would probably have worked as the search string would have been analysed.
i.e. ES would try to match "a" and "b" against a field containing "a" and "b" - this would be a successful match.

Comment: Or you could use not_analyzed for the uid field.